# How to change .max file associations?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, 3ds-max

I installed two 3DsMax in windows 8.1 
First I installed 3DsMax 2014
after that 3DsMax 2009

Now .max file will be open with 3DsMax 2009 and I want change it to open with 3DsMax 2014

I changed Open With section but It open with Max 2009 and I changed Control Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations max file type asscociation default but it don't work yet

is there any way for change it for open with 3DsMax 2014 , registry or anything others way

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the registry easily if you know how:

1. Open *regedit* and navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.max`.
2. Note the **(Default)** value in the right-hand pane - this is the *ProgID* for the file type.
3. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\<ProgID>\shell\open\command` and edit its **(Default)** value to reflect the path to the executable you want to use.

If you're not comfortable editing the registry directly, you can use something like [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) instead. It's portable so just download it, extract and run and then:

1. Select **.max** from the *File types* pane on top.
2. Right-click **open** from the *Actions* pane below and select *Edit*.
3. Modify the executable path (and *only* the path) as shown below, then OK your way out and you're done:

   [image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 8.1 you will need to change the Open With selection to the 3DsMax 2014 executable. To do this:

1. Right-click on a .max file
2. In the pop up menu, click Open with...
3. In the dialog box, click More Options
4. Scroll down in the dialog box, click Look for another app on this PC
5. In the window that opens, navigate to the executable for 3DsMax 2014
6. Select the executable and click Open.

Now any future .max files will open with the 2014 version rather than 2009.

Comment: oh, Thanks for your answer but i did that before, even I changed default program from Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations but It will open with 3DsMax 2009 yet, I think it need change from registry, but i don't know how can do that